# ld: library not found for -lPods-SmartSuite-Bolts Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Trying to add Cocoapods to my project. When I compile it gives me this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-SmartSuite-Bolts
```

I tried re-installing Cocoapods, deleting the workspace, etc. I have the inherit flag in Other linker flags. Looks like it is a specific thing relating to Bolts. May be because I have both Parse and Facebook sdk in the project. Tried to google, there is much on -lPods, but this is a specific error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Removing Cocoapods from the project completely and adding it again finally solved the problem.